# Aplicación localización segundo plano no funciona en Samsung Android 8.0

Tags: android, geolocalización

Tengo una aplicación de localización que se ejecuta en segundo plano. Para gestionar todo esto, hago uso de alarmas periódicas para activar el proceso de localización. El problema es que desde la ***última actualización de SAMSUNG*** ha dejado de funcionar en estos dispositivos. Cuando el dispositivo está bloqueado esas alarmas dejan de funcionar. Con solo activar de nuevo la pantalla todo vuelve a funcionar correctamente. He probado varios método para la gestión de las alarmas y las últimas pruebas las he realizado con el método ***setExactAndAllowWhileIdle***

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Pero el resultado ha sido el mismo. Este comportamiento me sucede en dispositivos Samsung con Android 8.0.

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia será bienvenida.

Gracias

Comment: Android 8 hizo grandes cambios respecto a los procesos en segundo plano. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background?hl=es-419

Comment: Agrega más detalles, ¿ te refieres a alarmManager ?, ¿Sobrescribes los métodos onPause() onResume()?, sería importante un poco de código para saber que clases y métodos usas probablemente algunos necesitan cambios o son obsoletos, revisar [ask].